# TypeScript return object with same properties as generic parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've build a React hook called `useValidation` that checks a set of passed validation functions with a certain value. The `validators` parameter is a generic type so I can return a object with the same properties ( the checked validation functions ) but with a value of `true/false` depending on what the validation function returned. Now I have to set an initial state in the `React` `useState` hook. I can't seem to get the types right though. Here is my hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function useValidation<
  K,
  T extends {
    [key: string]: (value: K) => boolean;
  }
>(
  value: K,
  validators: T
): {
  valid: boolean;
  results: { [key in keyof T]: boolean };
} {
  const [results, setResults] = useState<
    { [key in keyof T]: boolean }
  >(??????);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newResults: {
      [key in keyof T]: boolean;
    } = Object.assign({}, results);

    for (const key in validators) {
      const valid = validators[key](value);
      newResults[key] = valid;
    }

    setResults(newResults);
  }, [results, validators, value]);

  const valid = Object.values(results).every(
    (item) => item === true
  );

  return { valid, results };
}
```

I want to set all the values of the returned object as the initial value, but how can I execute what is inside the `useEffect` hook for the initial value. I'm looking for a function like this that I can then call inside the `useState` hook and get the initial value:

```
function getInitialResults<
  K,
  T extends {
    [key: string]: (value: K) => boolean;
  }
>(
  value: K,
  validators: T
): { [key in keyof T]: true} {
  const initialResults = {};

  for (const key in validators) {
   const valid = validators[key](value);
   initialResults[key] = valid;
  }

  return initialResults;
}
```

Here is the link to the **TypeScript Playground** that shows the error [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQJJhrAhgGwCVUBnEfKEgHgChFEBpAGjsQBVFUAPKVMAExKIA3q3oBtANaoAngC5EJKACcYYZAF0FACgBuBEKgUMAlIgC8APkQAjOHHypcYANysAvjUvbW%20-IeMWej8YflwoOGUSBTYaEwVhRClZRDVEaRk4YHYtRBVDdxFWCAQlVOw8IlJySgsRdzdWYEjEbRKwMozyxBCwiKizUXpEdrLeut7wyJJkmQ09A1QTN2G1HBgCYjIKGYyNCYJQlcRPVmV0EGUkNcqtmpI3dyA)

Comment: Why are you declaring that the return value's properties will be `true` when it looks like they are `boolean`?  My suggestion would be something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQJJhrAhgGwCVUBnEfKEgHgChFEBpAGjsQBVFUAPKVMAExKIA3q3oBtANaoAngC5EJKACcYYZAF0FACgBuBEKgUMAlIgC8APkQAjOHHypcYANysAvjUvbW+-IeMWej8YflwoOGUSBTYaM1F6CAQlRDUcGAJiMgohcxF3RFwhYUQpWVSkaRk4YHYtW3tHZ0R3N1ZgSMRtJLAUqorEELCIqPixRB6UoYtBglDwyJIymQ09A1QTN3p6NLwiUnJKZY0Zoa2WmlZldBBlJF2M-ezKN3cgA) but I don't know if I understand the use case

Comment: @jcalz The `true` was a leftover from my experimentation. I'm sorry, it's supposed to be `boolean`. Thanks for your suggestion. However, using a type assertion is obviously not optimal because it breaks the type checking? Is it acceptable to use type assertion in this case?

Comment: Using a type assertion to loosen checking while you're building an object (so it starts off as a lie and ends up being true) is a common pattern so I'd say it's acceptable.  You might be able to write something more type safe but it will be more complicated for little benefit.

Comment: A compromise if you intend to do this often is to move the property mapping to its own `mapProps()` function so the type assertion only happens in a central place, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcAKAnO6DOAPACqICmAHlGWACb6JwBGAVmdADSICqAfABTMWALkTEuEJqP4A3VABtRxANoBrMgE84wMQF0uq0eq07iASkQBeXjwsBvAFCJEEBPiiJsZD5cR2AvoioDHaIygDSiDBIxtp6otyI-gDcTojAcNiI-K5g7oiqUUhC9mnOXlBqulYuTIKsVQZmqc7+aRUg2EgVqf5AA) and then you would `mapProps(validators, v => v(value))` inside your function